# How can I track down the cause of a memory fault when using JNA to access a native method?

Tags: java, pointers, struct, jna

Calling the native method wich is listed below via JNA is causing an **Invalid memory access**.

This is what I googled and stackoverflowed to do with a struct**.

```
DLLEXPORT int STDCALL func( const struct someStruct* s, const float someFloat, enum someEnum, struct structOfInterest** soi);
```

This is how the method func is called:

```
PointerByReference p = new PointerByReference();
int result = _native.func(s, f, 1, p);
```

Is there a way to get more information for the cause of the Invalid memory access exception?

EDIT: 
the java declaration.

```
int func(someStruct s, float someFloat, int someEnum, PointerByReference p);
```

the type of someStruct is extending Structure. also including this line

```
class ByReference extends someStruct implements Structure.ByReference {}
```

Comment: Show your Java declaration.  The first argument should be a `Structure` (`Structure.ByReference` is implied).  The final argument should be `PointerByReference`, and you use `PointerByReference.getValue()` after the call to obtain the `Pointer` from which you can initialize a new `Structure` instance.  You need to also ensure that your method is using the stdcall calling convention; if it's not that could also cause your crash.

Comment: Are you certain that the `struct**` parameter is what's causing the invalid memory access?  If not, how could you ascertain that that is the cause and not one of the other parameters or some aspect of the call itself (calling convention)?

Comment: the reason for the exception is the struct someStruct*. First I allocate some native memory with new Memory(...). Then I copy data from a DataBuffer. The Pointer on this memory is used inside the someStruct.

Comment: JNA automatically allocates all required memory for any given `Structure`.  However, if you fail to properly initialize any application-specific data, or pass in a buffer and incorrectly identify its size, you will likely get memory faults.  Please note that _none_ of what you mention here in your comment is included in your question.